# How do I fix substring not working in vue.js 3?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, typeerror, vuejs3

I'm new in vuejs, and I'm trying to fetch posts from a JSON file using the composition API, but I'm having a problem. After fetching post, too many texts are being displayed, which is what I don't want. I have tried to fix it using the following method:

```
<template>
    <div class="max-w-md bg-white rounded-xl shadow-md overflow-hidden md:max-w-2xl m-6" v-for="post in post" :key="post.id">
        <div class="md:flex">
            <div class="md:flex-shrink-0" >
            <img class="h-48 w-full object-cover md:h-full md:w-48" src="assets/store.jpg" alt="Man looking at item at a store">
            <div class="p-8">
            <div class="uppercase tracking-wide text-sm text-indigo-500 font-semibold">News</div>
            <router-link :to="{name: 'Details', params:{id: post.id}}"><strong>{{post.title}}</strong></router-link>
            <p class="mt-2 text-gray-500">{{snippet}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { computed } from 'vue'
export default {
    props:['post'],
    setup(props) {
        const snippet = computed(() => {
            return props.post.body.substring(0,100) + '...'
        }) 
        return{snippet}
    }
}
</script>
```

The problem here is that when I run this piece of code, I get an error that says:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')

And I don't even know how to go about this at the moment. Could someone please help?

Comment: Looks like `props.post.body` is not defined. Please verify that `props.post.body` has a string value.

Answer (score 1):

We can handle the undefined error by checking the properties value.

```
const snippet = computed(() => {
    let body = ''
    if (props.post && props.post.body){
      body = props.post.body.substring(0,100) + '...'
    }
    return body
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`props.post.body` is `undefined`. It's better to debug why it's undefined.
Nevertheless, if the `undefined` can be ignored you can use the following ES10 **optional chaining** operator.

`props.post.body?.substring(0,100)`

Answer (score 0):

return String(props.post.body).substring(0,100) + '...';

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).